# Javascript xmlhttprequest always

Tags: javascript, http, google-chrome, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to do a chat application, so I need it to ALWAYS receive the server information. So, when the request finishes,  in the:

```
http.onreadystatechange=function(){
```

I've put another call to the function, again, so:

```
request();
```

Then everything happens in a loop. The problem is that it is only working in google chrome. The explorer and firefox, don't wait until the  `get.onreadystatechange=function()`, then just keep calling return() like 100 times a second, for no reason :(

```
function request()
{
    var get;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        get = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    document.getElementById("request_status").innerHTML = "requests: "+requests;
    get.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
     if (get.readyState==4 && get.status==200)
       {
        requests+=1;
        request();
       }
    }
    get.open("GET","request.php",true);
    get.send();
}
```

In google chrome, the 'requests' grow like 4 per second. In explorer and firefox they grow like 200 per second, so something is wrong!

Comment: Look at the Net tab in the developer tools. Are you getting cached results?

Comment: +1 for caching. I've created a jsFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/UkYBG/4/ In IE in case of 302 responses `requests` are incrementing very fast

Answer (score 0):

I can't check Explorer, but Firefox works for your example when I do it in this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZHdgb/1/

Although it seems to work for me, maybe try making these synchronous requests so only one fires at a time. See below:

Change

`get.open("GET","request.php",true);`

To:

`get.open("GET","request.php",false);`

Answer (score -1):

At the end of your function, you will want to use `setTimeout(functionHere(), timeInMilisHere)` to continuously call your function after a designated time in ms

Comment: But if I call it when it ends, I don't need time, and the function will be called at the greatest possible velocity

Comment: what do you mean you don't need time? like the time didnt have any affect on the function being called?

Comment: I don't need to use the delay to call the function in an interval, because I already call it when it finishes. So it goes as faster as possible

Comment: instead of `request();` use `setTimeout(request(), 1000);` that'll space out the calls by 1 second, if you want more, than chagne the time

Comment: but then I will get a lot of requests that didn't complete. It's better for me to only ask for a new request when the last one has finished, don't?

Comment: `setTimeout()` will wait for the request to complete, then wait however long (in my example 1 second), before sending a new request